# Fit tootltip in Leaflet map window after flyto()

Tags: leaflet, marker

When I `flyto()` to marker and `openTooltip()` on it, the marker turn up on center point of map area, and part of the Tooltip turn up is outside the map-window. How make flyto() centered on Tooltip instead of them marker? Or in another way fit Tooltip into map-area.

```
map.flyTo(L.latLng(item.lat, item.lon), 14, {
            animate: true,
            duration: 1.0});
item.marker.openTooltip();
```

[image description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/04xGc.jpg)

Comment: please explain more and take it your image of screen

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Updated description